# How to change the routerlink in nav bar in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, url, routes

I am having the issue of routing to a incorrect routelink. How to avoid this?
sorry for being a noob.

The error I am getting from Chrome console is

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL 
Segment: 'oadmin/add-new-student/add-new-teacher'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 
'oadmin/add-new-student/add-new-teacher'
```

HTML code of navigation buttons

```
<md-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar-student">  
<span >
    <button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu1">Student</button>
    <md-menu #menu1="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item [routerLink]="['add-new-student']" >Add New Student</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </md-menu>
  </span>
  <span >
    <button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu2">Teacher</button>
    <md-menu #menu2="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item [routerLink]="['add-new-teacher']" >Add New Teacher</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </md-menu>
  </span>
</md-toolbar>
```

My Routes

```
var routes = [
  {path: '',
  component: StudentComponent},
  {path: 'oadmin',
  component: OAdminComponent},
  {path: 'oadmin/add-new-student',
  component: NewStudentComponent},
  {path: 'oadmin/add-new-teacher',
  component: NewTeacherComponent},
];
```

Navigation bar is common for both routes.
When I click "Add New Teacher" route while being inside of "Add New Student" route, I am getting this error. and vice versa. How to avoid this?

Comment: another edit waiting approval but please remove the angularjs tag as that is for angular1x projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inside the `oadmin/add-new-student` path and you redirect to `add-new-teacher` you are being actually redirected to `oadmin/add-new-student/add-new-teacher` because writing `[routerLink]="['add-new-teacher']"` just appends `/add-new-teacher` to the current url. Instead what you want is to redirect to `oadmin/add-new-teacher` so instead of:

```
[routerLink]="['add-new-teacher']"
```

You should use this:

```
routerLink="/oadmin/add-new-teacher"
```

And you should also change it for add-new-student as if you visit the add-new-teacher and click on add-new-student link you will have the same error

```
<button md-menu-item routerLink="/oadmin/add-new-student" >Add New Student</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular 4 instead of relative path you need to mention the full path according to base href on index.html page
try

```
[routerLink]="['/oadmin/add-new-teacher']"
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining